# Finding $P(A∩B∩C^C)$ from other given probabilities

Tags: probability

Consider events A, B, and C for which $P(A)$ = $0.3$, $P(B)$ = $0.4$, $P(C)$ = $0.7$, $A$ and $B$ are independent, $A$ and $C$ are independent, $B$ and $C$ are independent, and $P(A∩B∩C)$ = $0.1$.  What is the value of $P(A∩B∩C^C)$?

Would I be correct in saying that $P(A∩B∩C^C)$ = $P(A∩B)$ - $P(A∩B∩C)$?

Then by independency of $A$ and $B$, $P(A∩B)$ = $P(A)P(B)$ = $.3(.4)$ = $.12$

$\Rightarrow$ $.12$ - $0.1$ = $.02$

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all three are independent and $P\left(C^C\right)=1-P(C)$, you can use $$P\left(A\cap B\cap C^C\right)=P(A)\,P(B)\,(1-P(C))$$ which then expands to what you have. So yes, your method is correct.

Comment: I was wondering this, but does $A$ $B$ $C$ pairwise independent imply independence as a trio?

Comment: Actually that's a good point; I hadn't thought about it. Intuitively I want to say yes. Regardless, the set $A\cap B \cap C^C$ is equal to the set $(A\cap B)-(A\cap B\cap C)$, so your method should work along that logic, at least for any similar problem I've come across. It's quite possible that all the problems I've seen have had the students assume independence though.

Comment: Upon searching, pairwise independent does NOT imply mutually independent, (though the converse holds); I apologise for my error

Comment: I have looked it up and it seems that it does not imply independence as a trio. The example I saw was with $3$ equal coins. Event $A$ is first two coins flipping the same, $B$ is second and third the same, and $C$ is first and third, and this seems to be a counter example. Having said that, your other point about the two sets being equal seems to stand so the conclusion remains the same! :)